# Best Android tablet for development

Tags: android, tablet

what android TABLET is best for development purposes? i have read same questions in this site, but it all about smart-phone development. 
Thanks.

Comment: you can purchase and develop for any tablet, difference lies in the various resolutions size, screen densities, prices and many more other criterias.

Comment: thanks, but i hope to get more specific advices. May be somebody can advice some specific tablet models?

Comment: Your questions lacks details. What do you want to develop? Is your app only for tablets? Do you need to test 3G, OpenGL, etc? Are you interested by pre-Honeycomb devices? Etc, etc..

Comment: I assume you REALLY mean, "Which tablet should I buy to identify as many things as possible that can break on a tablet, but work fine on a phone, and fix them so they're no longer broken on most tablets". If that's the case, I'd recommend ONLY a Honeycomb 3.1+ tablet with 1024x600 resolution or better. If you buy a $125 Froyo tablet with 480x800 display, you might as well test on a phone. Note that most cheap imported tablets are NOT real Honeycomb as of September 2011. You need the real thing. Offhand, I'd say Toshiba Thrive, Acer 500, Moto Xoom (good acid test - breaks a LOT of apps).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your consideration:
It is advisable to test your apps on low (or lowest) end devices, to reveal performance bottlenecks. An activity might take 2-3 seconds to load on a low-end cheap tablet, or a ListView might scroll jerkily, while your high-end dev tablet will not show this.
I have found that for Android, this means using the emulator for bottleneck tests - you might consider upping the provided RAM to 1024MB though, this makes it somewhat usable. Also, you could use a ramdisk for the emulator image.

For day to day development, I would also go with the Galaxy Tab 10, since you come to design your app specifically for dual-core processors. Or, ~100 bucks cheaper, the Motorola Xoom (but hurry up, I read that they already stopped production :)).

Comment: Exactly. Wouldn't buy Galaxy or Transformer tab for development. Buy a low-end model instead.

Comment: You can also buy a low-end smartphone and a high-end tablet if the performance-critical code is the same for both form factors.

Comment: IMHO, Toshiba Thrive is a better choice than the Galaxy Tab. The Tab is too "cloud-centric", which makes it a PITA for development. The Thrive has a real USB port (I think it can even mount USB flash drives), microSD that works as expected (Xoom doesn't/didn't), and user-swappable batteries (A500 doesn't). Xoom is a good acid test for compatibility because so any apps that work fine on phones break horribly on it (at least, as of 3.1). Tab seems to be the most tolerant of "phone" apps that break tablet rules (good for consumers, bad for developers. Think: trying to test poor html with IE6)

Comment: Could you please elaborate on "too cloud-centric"? Otherwise I agree - my philosophy regarding dev devices is "go with the crowd", since the crowd will decide over your market rankings.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO their is only one tablet that is really worth it = Galaxy Tab 10
http://www.samsung.com/global/microsite/galaxytab/10.1/index.html